# Flask and jsonify: Escaping characters

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask view which returns some JSON formatted data:

```
def myview():
    entities = get_my_entities()
    return jsonify({'entities': entities})
```

*entities* if a list of dictionaries; in each dictionary there is a value like *http://example.com/get/<user_id>/12345678* where *<user_id>* is a placeholder where the user should insert an indentifier that that have been given (and which should not appear in the JSON result).

The problem is, the *<user_id>* gets escaped and appears as *%3Cuser_id%3E*. Is there a way to stop the characters getting escaped?

Comment: That's not `jsonify()` doing that; it replaces `<` with `\u003c` and `>` with `\u003e` (perfectly valid JSON escape sequences). Something *else* is URL-escaping the angle-brackets.

Comment: How are you generating the urls with placeholders now?

Comment: Correction, `jsonify()` uses the regular encoder, not the HTML-safe version, so it doesn't even touch `<` or `>`.

Comment: I guessed it wasn't jsonify itself, but it does create the response object which (I assume) is at some point doing the escape.

The URLs are simply string formatted values; if I *print* them I see them with the &lt; and &gt; characters visible (not escaped).

Comment: You assume wrong. The response object doesn't touch the contents. Either your tool displaying the contents does the escaping, or the escaping happened *before* you called `jsonify()`.

Comment: You can return `repr(entities)` instead and look at, for example.

Comment: Thanks. My bad. I'm using url_for, which is doing it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Martijn. I'm using url_for to build the URLs, and its doing the escaping.